Copy activity in Azure Data fActory silently fails
I am using the ADF Copy Activity to extract an Office365 mailbox to Blob Storage.
I have the pipeline configured and running but it seems that it extracts incomplete data:
The source inputs a filter on date ranges. Specifically I am filtering on recievedDateTime like so:

Whenever I use a time range larger than 1 month, I get very little data in the blob storage (less than 20 Mb) and the line count is always a suspiciously round number (600, 800,...).
When I use smaller intervals- I as much as 200 Mb per month of data with a 'regular' non-round number of a few thousand emails.
I know for sure this is not accidental- there is no reduced activity in the mailbox at the 'problematic' time range.
I am new to ADF, so reaching out to how can I even troubleshoot this?
I've tried enabling logs but I do not see anything interesting there (as if they are not being written).
My backup plan is to perform the extraction in small intervals and perhaps automate this process but looking for something that "just works".

The Start and End Time should be in UTC, so can you try that by using ADF expressions like utcnow()?
